# How to efficiently search specific values in array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, database

Im wondering how to search big arrays using JavaScript.

Let's say we have an array consisting of elements that represent businesses. There are a couple thousand elements in the array, they are objects that sometimes also have arrays in them.

In each of those elements is a key e.g. called category that looks like this `category: ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"]`. Now I only want to find elements of the array that have a category like this:

```
category: ["Restaurant"]
```

The problem is that other keys of the elements in the array sometimes also have a property where "Restaurant" is in the name followed by something else e.g. "RestaurantPrice" so

```
if(array[i].categories != null && 
array[i].categories.indexOf("Restaurant") != -1) {
    do something
}
```

Would not work properly because it would return all occurences of the word "Restaurant" or am I wrong?

If not how should I search for specific things in an array?

Comment: `String.indexOf` matches substrings. `Array.indexOf` matches (whole) elements within the array. You didn't even test this, did you?

Comment: Didn't even know it existed

Answer (score 1):

If `categories` is an array like `["foobar", "foo"]`

`categories.indexOf("foo")` would return `1`, **foobar** would be ignored.

The other question was `how to find elements efficient?`.

It depends, if your set is static, you can prebuilt and cache some sort of index like:

```
var categoriesMap = {
  foobar: [1, 2, 4],
  foo: [1, 5, 7]
}
```

The array would represent the indexes of items, which includes the given categories.

Answer (score 1):

Try using HashMaps if your keys are unique.